# List: В чем разница между операциями append и + в цикле?

Tags: python, list

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

for row in a:
    row += [7]

print(a)
```

на выходе:
[[1, 2, 7], [3, 4, 7]]

а если так:

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

for row in a:
    row = row + [7]

print(a)
```

то выводит [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

в чем разница между операциями в цикле?

Answer (score 1):

Ну вы в общем-то уже всё правильно поняли.

Дело в том, что итератор `row` это ссылка (указатель) на элемент списка.

`row += [7]` работает так же, как `row.append(7)`, то есть **добавляет** элемент в готовый список, ссылка на который содержится в переменной `row`.

`row = row + [7]` **создаёт новый список** из элементов списка `row` и добавляемого списка и уже после этого присваивает ссылку на этот новый список в переменную цикла `row`. Таким образом, тот список, на который переменная `row` указывала в начале цикла, никак не меняется. Что мы и наблюдаем при печати значений.

Comment: @Kromster Так я вроде везде пишу, что это "ссылка на список". Думаете, слово "указатель" будет понятнее, чем "ссылка на список"? Я серьёзно спрашиваю.

Comment: @Kromster Да, так возможно ещё понятнее, спасибо )